# Lfs-image (lua) for esp32

Tags: docker, nodemcu, esp32

Is it possible to create a lfs-image for esp32?

I build the firmware with docker with the default `partitions.cvs`. (lfs size: 0x10000)

This command fails:

```
docker run --rm -ti -v `pwd`:/opt/nodemcu-firmware -v /home/me/ESP32_Lua/LFS/:/opt/lua marcelstoer/nodemcu-build lfs-image
```

Comment: What's the error msg?

Comment: Thanks for format my post. I'm not so competent in forums. Error: "No cross compiler found. You need to build the firmeware first."
The docker-command to build the firmware runs fine.

Comment: @paula78, if you want to expand refine your question and/or add details, it might be a good idea to edit the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not yet supported. You can use LFS on ESP8266 only.